# How to give space between two images in listiview?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, listitem

I am using listiview for my application,in my listiview i set something like this

listitem1(Image)
listitem2(Image+Image)

Now issue is in my second row i want to get space between two images,but it is not working,following is my xml layout and screen shot of my output

listview_view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F3F3F3"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/lnrsearchviews"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgshead"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_search"

        >
        <!--<ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/searchs"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            />-->

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/autosearchbyname"
        android:hint="Search"

        />

    </LinearLayout>

   <!-- <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt_shopbydept"
        android:text="Shop By Departments"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lnrsearchviews"
        />-->

    <ListView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_menu"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lnrsearchviews"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:divider="#f3f3f3"
        ></ListView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

list_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btntest"
            android:background="@drawable/ab"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:background="@drawable/heads"
        android:layout_weight="1.17">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="abd"
                android:id="@+id/txt_allproductsname"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="abddd"
                android:id="@+id/txt_allproductsquty"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Mygetview

```
http://pastie.org/10289187#5
```

Comment: can you post `getView()` part of the code too?

Comment: add android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" to the second layout which display the second image....

Comment: Where you are setting images ?

Comment: Why the widths for `RelativeLayout` (id) and `LinearLayout` (btntest) different? Try changing the width of btntest to 180dp (i.e. same as id-layout) and see if it works.

Comment: can you tell how to do that??

Comment: change the line `android:layout_width="150dp"` in `btntest` layout to `android:layout_width="180dp"`

Comment: @Gagan yet right side image smaller....

Comment: Did you change it from `150dp` to `180dp`? Did this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your `list_item` and use set visibility of the second `ImageView` to `gone` when you need to show only one image.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/first_imageview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#9ff0"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/second_imageview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#9ff0"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```